# twitter bootstrap prepend, append vertical misalignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Prepends and appends are off by about 3 pixels (the prepended and appended span is low)

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <form class="well">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="txtLot_Original_Cost">Original Cost</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                            <span class="add-on">$</span><input class="span2 numAlign" name="txtLot_Original_Cost" id="txtLot_Original_Cost" size="16" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The markup is in a very simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <%- body %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can override the problem with the following css:

```
.input-prepend .add-on {
    margin-right: -1px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:2px;
}
```

But I wonder what other side effects this will create.

Comment: Stackoverflow is based on a reputation system, a rep system that is based upon your approval of an answer. If you look at another question which has been answered you will notice that on the left of each question there is a green check mark plus an up/down arrow, that is used to mark the answer as correct and also upvote it if it deserves it. You have asked 9 questions so far and approved none and thus your approval rate is down to `0%`, something that might scare other answerer away because they might think that they are losing their time. FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I have determined that this occurs because I left a space between html elements. In a rather casual way, the docs suggest that spaces should not be included.

Comment: You should Post your answer then and approved in 24h. That's the best way to let people know you have found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed since twitter boostrap 2.0.3. You no longer need to overide with css.